# Usando Criteria para ordenação

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

No sistema que estou desenvolvendo estou tentando usar o criteria para conseguir executar uma query a qual não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar pelo jpql, então tentei executar segundo o material que tinha conseguindo chegando a esse codigo.

```
CriteriaBuilder crite = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
     CriteriaQuery<Peso> query = crite.createQuery(Peso.class);
     Root<Peso> root = query.from(Peso.class);

     Path<String> pathStatus = root.<Mapa>get("mapa").<String>get("status"); 
     Predicate predicateStatus = crite.equal(pathStatus, solicitado)       


     query.where(predicateStatus);

     query.orderBy(orders) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
     TypedQuery<Peso> q = em.createQuery(query);
```

O problema e que preciso ordenar minha querry, para isso coloquei o método orderBy, (DESTACADO NO CÓDIGO)mas ele so aceita variáveis do tipo Orde[] a qual não sei utilizar.
Se alguém poderia me informar como realizo essa ordenação agradeceria muito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A interface [CriteriaBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html) tem dois métodos que retornam um [Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Order.html), são eles:

```
/**
 * Create an ordering by the ascending value of the expression.
 *
 * @param x expression used to define the ordering
 *
 * @return ascending ordering corresponding to the expression
 */
 Order asc(Expression<?> x);
```

e

```
/**
 * Create an ordering by the descending value of the expression.
 *
 * @param x expression used to define the ordering
 *
 * @return descending ordering corresponding to the expression
 */
 Order desc(Expression<?> x);
```

No seu caso seria feito assim:

```
crite.asc("uma expressão") ou crite.desc("uma expressão")
```

A "expressão" você consegue com o seu `Root`, assim:

```
root.get("campo que você quer ordenar")
```

No geral seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
CriteriaBuilder crite = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Peso> query = crite.createQuery(Peso.class);
Root<Peso> root = query.from(Peso.class);

Path<String> pathStatus = root.<Mapa>get("mapa").<String>get("status"); 
Predicate predicateStatus = crite.equal(pathStatus, solicitado)       


query.where(predicateStatus);

query.orderBy(crite.asc(root.get("propriedade de ordenação"))) //Esse ponto muda
TypedQuery<Peso> q = em.createQuery(query);
```

Comment: Valeu! Denis! Seu post me ajudou muito